# REST API using complex SQL Operations

Tags: sql, rest, api-design

I have a bunch of normalized tables, called `danger`, `countermeasure` and `module`. 
Now I have a three column table `krt` representing the connection between the three tables. (column names `danger_id`, `countermeasure_id`, `module_id`)
The normal endpoints like `/danger` show the elements of the according table.

`/krt?where={result: module, danger_id: x}` would query the table `krt` for all dangers with danger_id == x and join the result with the module table.
The result would look like (converted for displaying)

```
danger_id:
 - module a
 - module b
danger_id2:
 - module ..
[...]
```

I could of course provide a view and add a custom endpoint for this view. But there are not only three possible views but even more complex ones with one or two additional joins. (can also provide an example if needed)

Therefore is this kind of querying and joining a common concept or do I violate any of the REST constraints with this design? Is there any better / more intuitive way to provide such kind of information?

Comment: Still hoping for someone with a little experience. I think it might at least break the cacheability principle as the underlying document is generated and not fetched from the database. On every request the join would have to be made again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking about how would the RESTful URL would look, it might be something like

`/krt?dangerId=x&result=module`

How you decide to build that SQL query is not related to RESTful design in my opinion.

There's also no guideline saying that every GET request has to be cacheable - it depends on other factors, too. If your data is fairly static, but requested often enough, then you might get away with caching it for even a short period of time.

Comment: The query type also is not really specified either - I simply used the JSON syntax. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Architectural_constraints) there are 6 constraints and cachability is one of them. Yes I can cache it but I cannot really monitor when the underlying data changes as it simply is too much data and not really bearable especially when many people are using it concurrently. Therefore I wouldn't call it "caching". Probably will do it like this neverless but it will not be a REST API for this reason.

Comment: "Responses must therefore, implicitly or explicitly, define themselves as cacheable, **or not**" - I would interpret that just as being able to apply caching - which you will technically be! Don't think for one second that all the GET requests of a RESTful API are cached - that's a business decision aswell.

Comment: I see your point - I can cache it. But not in terms of knowing when the underlying data changes I will update the cache but rather in terms a dumb cache which will keep the state e.g. for an hour. Good point.
Apart from that - do you think it matches the REST principle more or less?

Comment: You're better off having a look at the [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) rather than Wikipedia, especially if you're interested in targeting a specific level of RESTfulness

Comment: Cool, I did not hear about that before. In terms of that text the underlying representation appears to be relatively unimportant which is good. This also means the approach taken should be correct as long as I adhere to the other principles. Thanks!